Create smooth displaced surface meshes without high face counts
So I am trying to model a smooth surface for a lamp, that will eventually be 3d-printed.
I want it to look like this:

Unfortunately, to get this looking smooth, it needs a ridiculously high subdivision count, like 7 or 8 which results in this 'simple' design having many, many millions of faces and becoming a completely unwieldy mesh.
The problem is that with less subdivisions, which keeps the mesh very manageable, it looks like this:

My limited knowledge of 3D modeling tells me, that such a result would typically be done with a shader effect rather than actual in-mesh geometry, but since this needs to be 3d printed, it actually needs to be solid geometry.
Applying something like the smooth modifiers doesn't help, because the problem is that the quads are being "bent" over the generated ridges. In an ideal solution, I think I would want to somehow remesh this thing so that vertexes run along the ridgelines.

Does anyone have a good idea of how to generate forms like this (displaced noise wood texture) without absolutely blowing the mesh budget?

How the surface elevation is defined ? From a mathematical expression ? It looks like from the second picture to be computed on a XY cartesian grid.

@StefLAncien I used the displace modifier, set to texture mode, and used a wood grain noise texture

Welcome to computer graphics and 3d (this is a completely normal situation where you need more geometry or better topology)
Sometimes some forms need a lot of geometry. Since it needs to be 3d printed the geometry also needs to be real so no shader trick will work here.
What you could do is avoid all the unneeded topology subdividing creates by modelling it manually so you can make sure you only have topology you really need to hold the form. More deliberate topology can hold the same forms as larger amounts of uniform topology:

You could also use decimation that will also try to take forms into account automatically and may in some cases be the only practical approach even though it may deform the forms in some undesired ways. There is Decimate modifier for that or you have Decimate operator that you can use for selected geometry in edit mode:



Is there any procedural way of generating the better mesh topology like in your first example? A core goal is for me to be able to modify noise, size, distortion, etc and a hand-modeled approach loses that flexibility

Probably. You should ask another question specifically about that and geometry nodes, maybe someone could help with that.
